The test execution stops when an alert appears in the test step- Error: WebDriver Bidi command "browsingContext.handleUserPrompt" failed with error
Framework Webdriverio v9 with bidi
Test execution stops when an alert appears in a test step:
Error: WebDriver Bidi command "browsingContext.handleUserPrompt" failed with error: no such frame - Context xxxxx not found
at BidiHandler.send (file:///C:/San/qa-wdio-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/node.js:411:23)
at BidiHandler.browsingContextHandleUserPrompt (file:///C:/San/qa-wdio-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/node.js:654:31)
at Browser.value (file:///C:/San/qa-wdio-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/node.js:1200:26)
at Browser.wrapCommandFn (C:\San\qa-wdio-tests\node_modules@wdio\utils\build\index.js:884:32)
package.json entries:
"@wdio/allure-reporter": "^9.2.14",
    "@wdio/cli": "^9.4.1",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^9.3.1",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^9.2.14",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^9.4.1",
    "@wdio/shared-store-service": "^9.4.1",
    "@wdio/visual-service": "^6.2.2",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.32.0",
    "wdio-rerun-service": "^2.0.7",
    "wdio-wait-for": "^3.0.11"


issue resolved:
https://webdriver.io/blog/2024/08/15/webdriverio-v9-release/#automatic-dialog-handling
browser.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
console.log(dialog.message())
//await dialog.dismiss()    /// stops auto handling of alerts
})
await switchToParent() /// resolves no frame error and breaking of test execution
await acceptTheAlert() /// acts on alert
